# Why does my checkbox break after clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I'm creating a simple form with a few checkboxes but now every time I click, the buttons break. It looks like it is include in my script to assign a value of 'no' if a checkbox is not checked but I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yqwhxek4/6/

I have to include this script because i'm importing this form into a separate program and it will not allow me to use this solution:

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox_1" value="no">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" value="yes">
```

What in my script is causing it to break like that?

Comment: For starters, you have invalid HTML. You can't reuse an ID attribute in a single HTML document. A bit muddled right now from other stuff but I'm pretty sure you don't want to `name=""` them the same thing, either.

Comment: Also if your checkbox is set to be hidden with a value of no, and is appearing when you click yes, it's because it's changing the type from `hidden` to `checkbox` when you click on its label.

Comment: @TylerH the checkbox was copied and pasted in the fiddle for demo sake. I've updated it with a new id. Also, the checkbox is not appearing when clicked. The script only adds the hidden checkbox on submission. Click should toggle the checkbox on or off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're appending another checkbox element after the hidden one.

Check this update of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yqwhxek4/8/

```js
$('[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this);
  if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    checkbox.val('yes');
  } else {
    checkbox.val('no');
  }
});
```

```css
.col {
  float: none; 
  display: inline-block !important; 
  width: 33%; 
  text-align: center !important;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

/* -------------------------------------
 UNCHECKED CHECKBOXES
   ------------------------------------- */  

label.checkbox {
  border-radius: 20px; 
  border: 1px solid #ffffff; 
  padding-right:10px;
}

/* hide input */
input.checkbox:empty {
  margin-left: -9999px;
  }

input.checkbox:empty ~ label {
  position: relative; 
  float: left; 
  line-height: 1.25em; 
  text-indent: em; 
  margin-top: 1em; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none; 
  padding-top:15px; 
  padding-bottom: 15px; 
  width: 22px; 
  border:solid 2px #e5e5e5;
  height:2px;
}

input.checkbox:empty ~ label:before {
  position: absolute;  
  display: block; 
  top: 0;  
  bottom: 0;  
  left: 0; 
  content: ''; 
  width: 2em; 
  background: #eeeeee; 
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* hover */
input.checkbox:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
  content:'\2714'; 
  text-indent: .2em; 
  color: #aaaaaa; 
  padding-top:6px;
}

input.checkbox:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
  color: #aaaaaa;
}



/* -------------------------------------
 CHECKED CHECKBOXES
   ------------------------------------- */ 

input.checkbox:checked ~ label:before {
  content:'\2714'; 
  text-indent: .2em; 
  color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #34db9a; 
  padding-top:6px;
}

input.checkbox:checked ~ label {
  color: #777;
}

.checkboxItem {
  display:inline-block; 
  vertical-align:top; 
  margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="foo">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="moduleimg">
      <img spname="module_07.jpg" alt="" src="http://www.stolenimages.co.uk/components/com_easyblog/themes/wireframe/images/placeholder-image.png" style="max-width: 271px;" width="100%" height="auto" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxItem">
      <input name="hero_img" id="hero_img" class="checkbox" value="Yes" autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="hero_img" class="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="moduleimg">
      <img spname="module_07.jpg" alt="" src="http://www.stolenimages.co.uk/components/com_easyblog/themes/wireframe/images/placeholder-image.png" style="max-width: 271px;" width="100%" height="auto" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxItem">
      <input name="check2" id="check2" class="checkbox" value="Yes" autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="check2" class="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: for this script to work after importing the form I need to replicate the simple solution I described in my original question. On submission of the form, if there are any unchecked checkboxes, the script will create a hidden checkbox field with the same id and submit that field with a value of 'no'. The hidden field will overwrite the default value of the original unchecked checkbox which by default submits as "undefined"

Comment: Well, the question was about your HTML breaking after clicking the checkbox, about this comment now, it's undefined because when you submit a form with elements containing the same `name` attribute, it becomes an array in your server side code, so you need to retrieve the value as such. In this example, you have `hero_img` submitted twice.

Comment: Someone else pointed that out and I updated the fiddle in my original question. The checkboxes were duplicated to show the demo. When the id's are unique I would still need the added hidden checkbox with a value of no. Is there anything in my CSS that I could change to prevent this from happening? The buttons don't just break when I click the checkbox. They break if I click anywhere on the page: https://jsfiddle.net/yqwhxek4/6/

Comment: I don't get why do you need the `hidden` input, your checkbox is already hidden. Just changing the value of the existing one to `no` should help.

Comment: About this error of breaking clicking anywhere it's because you binded your `click` event to the form, not to the `checkbox` where it should be.

Comment: I've made an update to the code, check it out.

Comment: The checkboxes are currently not hidden, just pushed to the side so that you can't see them. All checkboxes are visible before submission. On submission, the script adds a new hidden checkbox that will override the value of any unchecked checkboxes. And the click event needs to be attached to the form in order for the script to submit the value of 'no'

Comment: Why not use `display: none;` instead of `margin-left: -9999px;`?

Comment: display: none; disables my hover activity which is nice to have but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle with the clone and `.after().append(` does not really make sense to me as you have it.  <s>Perhaps you simple mean to check.uncheck the checkbox and manipulate the attribute "value"?  (Note that checkboxes typically do not have a "value" but are simply checked/unchecked (boolean value).</s>

Proposed code change:(still I do not like the click handler on the "#foo" but let's bypass that for now.)

```
$('#foo').on('click', '.checkboxItem', function() {
  var currCbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
  currCbox.attr('value', currCbox[0].checked ? 'yes' : 'no');
});
```

Markup  I tested with: (no duplicate ID and changed label for it)

```
<form id="foo">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="moduleimg"><img spname="module_07.jpg" alt="" src="http://www.stolenimages.co.uk/components/com_easyblog/themes/wireframe/images/placeholder-image.png" style="max-width: 271px;" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>
    <div class="checkboxItem">
      <input name="hero_img0" id="hero_img0" class="checkbox" value="Yes"  autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="hero_img0" class="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="moduleimg"><img spname="module_07.jpg" alt="" src="http://www.stolenimages.co.uk/components/com_easyblog/themes/wireframe/images/placeholder-image.png" style="max-width: 271px;" width="100%" height="auto" /></div>
    <div class="checkboxItem">
      <input name="hero_img" id="hero_img" class="checkbox" value="Yes" autocomplete="off" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="hero_img" class="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Testable fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/ydngkoxk/

Comment: There's no `checked` property in `checkbox` because it's a jQuery object, it should be `checkbox[0].checked`

Comment: Yes, fast typing, fixed the reference

Comment: This solution does the opposite of what I need. It turns all the yes values into 'undefined' and my unchecked checkboxes into a value of 'yes'. Also, if I click anywhere other than a checkbox it will check all of them at the same time

Comment: @cgrouge - updated with simplified code based on this comment.  Difficult from the question to determine exact desired functionality.